# JNI method doesn't callback Java method

Tags: android, callback, java-native-interface

**Solved : I needed to create a new object before calling the method !**

I have been trying to call a Java method from JNI. The call works and the app does not crash, but the JAVA method doesn't get called either.

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

My JNI code :

```
jclass test_method = findClass("com/package/Test");

if (test_method == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "failed to find test");
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "found test object");
}
jmethodID test_const =  env->GetMethodID(test_method, "<init>", "(I)V");

jobject employeeObject = (env)->NewObject(test_method, test_const, 800);

if (employeeObject == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "failed to find object");
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "found emp object");
}
jclass myclass = findClass("com/package/TestObj");

if(myclass == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "Couldnt find myclass");
    return;
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "Found myclass");
}

g_clazz = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(myclass);

if (g_clazz == NULL) {
    fLogPrintf(LOG_DEBUG,"Failed to find class");
}
new_method = env->GetMethodID(g_clazz, "setParams", "(Lcom/package/Test;)V");

if (new_method == 0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "failed to find method");
}

(*env).CallVoidMethod(g_clazz, new_method, employeeObject);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "succesfully finished  calling method");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
}

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "JNI", "Detaching current thread");
m_jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

My Java code :

```
package com.package; 

class TestObj { 
    public void setParams(Test test) {
        Log.e("Oops", " Callback successfully called!");
    }
}
```

When i run the app it runs perfectly without any errors/crash, I also get the "successfully finished calling method" and "detaching current thread" logs which indicate JNI was able to call my function successfully but when I check the logs for the Java method setParams I see no logs at all.

Any idea what am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: new_method = env->GetMethodID(g_clazz, "setParams", "(Lcom/package/Test;)V"); I think your arguments in this line are wrong, should Test be TestSIP?

Comment: Oops thats a typo, its supposed to be Test. Updated the question. Also I don't think the naming is the problem as it doesn't crash which it would normally if the naming was wrong. I get all the logs to the end

Comment: env->GetMethodID does not return an Object, but 0 if the method has not been found, you should be checking for that. The NULL check doesn't work because it never returns NULL.

Comment: Just tried that, it doesn't return 0. So it finds the method

Comment: Yes all methods are found. I replaced all method checks from NULL to 0. It finds all the methods, thats the more confusing part. I don't get it what is wrong

Comment: @RolfSmit Got it working, apparently I needed to create a new object of the class before calling the method. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: @RolfSmit NULL and 0 are indistinguishable in this context.

Comment: But for readability i prefer to use 0

Comment: @RolfSmit So do I, and so does Bjarne Stroustrup, but it doesn't affect the execution of the code. A check for NULL functions identically to a test for zero here. Your comment above doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

**I needed to create a new object before calling the method !**  So i just added the following lines of code before calling the method :

```
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(g_clazz, "<init>", "(I)V"); 
jobject test_object = env->NewObject(g_clazz, constructor, 48);
```

And then finally modified the final call to method as  :

```
(*env).CallVoidMethod(test_object, new_method, 23);
```

The previous call was wrong :

```
(*env).CallVoidMethod(g_clazz, new_method, 23);
```

Using g_clazz was the problem

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you didn't already have an object why are you calling an instance method at all?

Comment: I was trying to call the function using the class that was returned to me , instead I had to explicitly create a new object and use that object to call the method.